# In Javascript index order in constructing array of objects is always 0,1,...n

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

While constructing array of objects from nested array of objects using nested forEach. Using outer loop value as key value to the object and pushing into the array. Finally array changes that value to index value from 0,1,...n. In my case, they key name is **y**, I tried to setting outloop index as value to y but in final array. it displays as 0,1,..n.

Tried with hardcoding y key value. even in that case it changes to 0,1..n values.

Tried console.log in each loop on that time. y value is correct. but in the end it changes.

I guess I missed something wrong in creating a object like created with reference to the old object. its value changes like that.

Sample Input JSON

```
 { "result":[
         {
            "refid":"3dfasdfasdfasdf",
            "summaryDisplayName":"3dfasdfasdfasdf",
            "workflow":[
               {
                  "statusCode":"SUB",
                  "statusName":"Submitted",
                  "startDate":"2019-10-25T11:31:27.000+00:00",
                  "endDate":"2019-10-28T14:40:41.000+00:00",
               },
               {
                  "statusCode":"PRO",
                  "statusName":"Reviewed",
                  "startDate":"2019-10-28T14:24:11.000+00:00",
                  "endDate":"2019-10-28T14:25:58.000+00:00",
               },
               {
                  "statusCode":"APR",
                  "statusName":"Approved",
                  "startDate":"2019-10-28T14:28:33.000+00:00",
                  "endDate":"2019-10-28T14:28:38.000+00:00",
               }
            ],
            "temp":false
         }]}
```

````
responseJson.forEach(function(value:any, summaryIndex:any){
    value['workflows'].forEach(function(workflow:any, workflowIndex:any){
      workflowData = {
        y: summaryIndex, /<----***** expected value of the summaryIndex but got serial number from 0 to n ***/
        start: new Date(workflow['startDate']).getTime(),
        end: new Date(workflow['endDate']).getTime(),
        // color: this.legendPalette[workflow['statusName']],
        custom: workflow['history'],
      };
      this.workflowArray.push(workflowData);
     })

     
  })```

  console.log("workflowArray ", this.workflowArray);

**responseJson** - is a Array of objects with contains workflows key.
**workflows** - is a Array of objects of statuses.

Expected to have array of object with y value as grouped with summaryIndex but got 0,1...n.

Expected:

[{
y: 0,
start: "SOME_VALUE",
end: "SOME_VALUE",
custom: "SOME_VALUE"
},{
y: 0,
start: "SOME_VALUE",
end: "SOME_VALUE",
custom: "SOME_VALUE"
},{
y: 0,
start: "SOME_VALUE",
end: "SOME_VALUE",
custom: "SOME_VALUE"
},{
y: 1,
start: "SOME_VALUE",
end: "SOME_VALUE",
custom: "SOME_VALUE"
}]

But Got.

[{
y: 0,
start: "SOME_VALUE",
end: "SOME_VALUE",
custom: "SOME_VALUE"
},{
y: 1,
start: "SOME_VALUE",
end: "SOME_VALUE",
custom: "SOME_VALUE"
},{
y: 2,
start: "SOME_VALUE",
end: "SOME_VALUE",
custom: "SOME_VALUE"
},{
y: 3,
start: "SOME_VALUE",
end: "SOME_VALUE",
custom: "SOME_VALUE"
}]
````

Comment: *index of the summaryIndex* — what does that mean?

Comment: I tried to assign index value of outer forEach.

Comment: Well the outer index value is going to be 0 for all of the iterations of the inner `.forEach()` in the first pass of the outer `.forEach()`. Then it will be 1, then 2, etc.

Comment: Can you paste here sample input data ?

Comment: The second parameter passed to the `.forEach()` callback is the index into the array. Thus it will always be 0, 1, 2, etc up to the length of the array.

Comment: Updated input JSON

Comment: But I am using outer foreach index. Y key should have that index. right? @Pointy

Comment: Oh wait: you have not declared `workflowData`. Declare it with `let`.

Comment: In 2021 there's really no reason not to program in "strict" mode.

Comment: I declared it in above this code snippet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230088/discussion-between-dhananjayan-and-pointy).

Answer (score 0):

I am assigning constructed array of objects as input to high charts gantt chart. that time, *y* value is changed to 0,1..N by the library. then console.log reflect the lastest object.